# how to find out carrier's name in javascript or php

Tags: javascript, php, carrier

I need to create a unique id for every mobile device that access my webpage. I already got the user's screen resolution, browser, OS and location, but I also want to know the carrier's name to make it more accurate.

So far I have:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="Javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="Javascript" src="http://api.easyjquery.com/easyjquery.js"></script>


<?PHP

$browsers = array ();
$osS = array ();
$tb_query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM cst_unique_device_index"); 
while ($rw_query=mysql_fetch_array($tb_query)){
  extract ($rw_query);
  $variable = strtolower($variable); 

  if ($type == 2) $browsers[] = $variable;
}

$osS = array (
    "android",
    "bada",
    "blackberry",
    "brew",
    "ios",
    "lg",
    "linux",
    "motorola",
    "nintendo",
    "palm",
    "playstation",
    "samsung",
    "series",
    "sony",
    "symbianos",
    "unknown",
    "webos",
    "wince",
    "windows");


  $agent = strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
  foreach($browsers as $browser)
    {
    if (preg_match("#($browser)[/ ]?([0-9.]*)#", $agent, $matchBrowser))
      {
      $user_browser = $matchBrowser[1] ;
      $user_browser_version = $matchBrowser[2] ;
      break ;
      }
    }

  foreach($osS as $os)
    {
    if (preg_match("#($os)[/ ]?([a-z0-9.]*)#", $agent, $matchOS))
      {
      $user_os = $matchOS[1];
      $user_os_version = $matchBrowser[2] ;
      }
    }




echo $agent .'<br />'    ;
echo '
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Screen: </th>
        <td id="user_screen"></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Browser: </th>
        <td>' . $user_browser . '</td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>OS: </th>
        <td>' . $user_os . '</td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>State: </th>
        <td id="user_state"></td>
        <td></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <th>Carrier: </th>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>

    ';
?>


<script type="text/javascript" language="Javascript">
var screenWith = screen.width      
var screenHeight = screen.height

document.getElementById('user_screen').innerHTML = screenWith+"x"+screenHeight;


    // 1. Your Data Here
    function my_callback(json) {
        alert("IP :" + json.IP + " nCOUNTRY: " + json.COUNTRY);
    }

    function my_callback2(json) {
        // more information at http://api.easyjquery.com/test/demo-ip.php
        //alert("IP :" + json.IP + " nCOUNTRY: " + json.COUNTRY + " City: " +         json.cityName + " regionName: " + json.regionName);
        document.getElementById('user_state').innerHTML = json.cityName;
    }

    // 2. Setup Callback Function
   // EasyjQuery_Get_IP("my_callback"); // fastest version
    EasyjQuery_Get_IP("my_callback2","full"); // full version


</script>
```

Comment: I believe his question is:  `How can I get the name of the carrier from the request?`

Comment: try this: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/detect.html or http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_nav_useragent.asp

Comment: Thanks, but these examples give me the info I already have. What I'm trying to calculate is a unique device probability, knowing Android market Share, Mobile OS Market Share, Mobile Browser Market Share, Mobile Screen Resolution Share and Carrier Market Share.

Answer (score 2):

It would be a security issue if you could get this directly. A browser runs in a sandbox and should not be able to get that data.

You could log ip addresses and lookup the ranges of every carrier. That would be a smart guess I think.

You can get them from e.g. http://whois.arin.net/ui

```
AT&T
32.0.0.0 - 32.255.255.255 
166.128.0.0 - 166.255.255.255
```

Answer (score 1):

you can get user carrier name from ip address.

```
<?php
$ip = $_REQUEST['REMOTE_ADDR']; // the IP address to query
$query = @unserialize(file_get_contents('http://ip-
api.com/php/'.$ip));
if($query && $query['status'] == 'success') {
  echo 'Hello visitor from '.$query['country'].', '.$query['city'].'!';
} else {
  echo 'Unable to get location';
}
?>
```

this is working for me i hope also working for you. :)

Comment: This code, however, provides you with the country and the city, rather than the carrier's name, as OP requested.