# Detect network operator using javascript

Tags: javascript

When a user connects to a WAP (wireless access point) via a 3G connection, how does one detect the network operator client using JavaScript?

Comment: I don't believe this is possible.

Comment: You cannot do this using (client side) JavaScript. Your best bet will be to get the clients IP on your server, and do a network whois to match the allocated block against known operators; you *might* (if you're lucky) find existing datasets to do this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11194309/how-to-find-out-carriers-name-in-javascript-or-php

Answer (score 1):

It is **not** possible to detect the ISP provider **using only** JavaScript. But you can use the [Network Information API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Network_Information_API) to get information about the system's connection in terms of general connection type (e.g., 'wifi', 'cellular', etc.).

**A possible solution for you could be:**

> To write JavaScript logic which use third party services & APIs to get
>   the ISP information for a given IP Address.

For example, you can use [IP Info](http://ipinfo.io)'s APIs. Here's an example of the details it provides:

```
$ curl ipinfo.io
{
  "ip": "67.188.232.131",
  "hostname": "c-67-188-232-131.hsd1.ca.comcast.net", // This is the data you're looking for
  "city": "Milpitas",
  "region": "California",
  "country": "US",
  "loc": "37.44040000000001,-121.87049999999999",
  "org": "AS7922 Comcast Cable Communications, Inc.",
  "postal": "95035",
  "phone": 408
}
```

You can refer to http://ipinfo.io/developers for more information about their APIs. Or you can choose among tons of such other APIs/services.